# Types of parameters 'subscriber' and 'subscriber' are incompatible when sharing files between projects

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting the following error when using a project structure where I'm sharing files between two sub-projects:

```
root
└ api (Node/Express)
    └ node_modules
    └ src
      └ schema
        └ resource.d.ts
    └ ...
└ cli (Angular)
    └ node_modules
    └ src
    └ ...
```

In my Angular client `cli` I have the following `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../api/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm importing the `resource.d.ts` file from `api` project like so

```ts
import { ItemListHead } from '@shared/schema/resource';
```

The error looks like this

```
Error: src/app/list/list.component.ts:36:5 - error TS2322: Type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<import("D:/ts/api/src/schema/index").Field[][]>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<import("D:/ts/api/src/schema/index").Field[][]>'.
  Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<any> | undefined'.
      Type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<any>'.
        Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
          Type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Operator").Operator<any, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Operator").Operator<any, any> | undefined'.
            Type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Operator").Operator<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Operator").Operator<any, any>'.
              Types of property 'call' are incompatible.
                Type '(subscriber: import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types").TeardownLogic' is not assignable to type '(subscriber: import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types").TeardownLogic'.
                  Types of parameters 'subscriber' and 'subscriber' are incompatible.
                    Property '_finalizers' is missing in type 'import("D:/ts/api/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>' but required in type 'import("D:/ts/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>'.
```

so the problem is coming from `Observable` type (rxjs) in my `ItemListHead` type:

```ts
interface ItemListHead {
  pages: Dictionary<Observable<Field[][]> | null>;
}
```

Both projects `api` and `cli` use the same version of `rxjs` (`^7.5.0`). I'v already reinstalled packages in both, which did not help.

Comment: A quick search b/n RxJS v7.5.2 and v7.8.1 for string `'_finalizers'` shows that it's not present in v7.5.2, which means there's a version mismatch b/n the projects. For such dependencies, I'd recommend not using the range identifier like caret (`^`) for version numbers. Remove node_modules and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock if using `yarn`) in both projects, change the versions in both projects to `"rxjs": "7.5.2"` or whatever version you wish _without_ any range identifiers (`^` or `~`) and run `npm install` (or `yarn install`).